# Does saving after completing the Suicide Mission count?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I am thinking of getting the DLC for Mass Effect 2 and completing it but i rather not have to start a new game and go though the entire thing just for a couple of extra missions.

i am wondering, after clearing the suicide mission and choosing to continue to play, can i do extra missions (and thus newly added DLC Missions) and just save where ever **and have Mass Effect 3 pick up the changes** or do i have to complete the Suicide Mission again.

Comment: I thought I had seen this question before, but perhaps it was for one of the other games in the series.  Suffice it to say, at least for ME2, you can play DLC (and base game missions) on the same save after completing the story.

Comment: @MBraedley and that does get picked up in Mass Effect 3? (i know actions in the Arrival DLC changes the outcome of Citadel: Baterian Codes)

Comment: Oh, hmm, I'm not sure.  Good thing I didn't actually answer.  I can't remember if it takes the save immediately after completing the story, or the last save that's made.

Comment: @MBraedley maybe the Mass Effect 3 thing might have been lost in the second paragraph so i've bold it for future reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the Mass Effect 2 DLC is playable after the Suicide Mission. Some of it can be played before, but it can all be played after.

Decisions made during DLC missions played after the Suicide Mission are imported into Mass Effect 3. I played all of the post-release Mass Effect 2 DLC after finishing the Suicide Mission (Kasumi, Overlord, Lair of the Shadow Broker, and Arrival) and imported my Mass Effect 2 save into Mass Effect 3. My Mass Effect 3 play through did honor the decisions I made during the Mass Effect 2 DLC missions.